# Eloquent relation count problems

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent

I currently have the following problem that

```
$eloquentEntity->relation->count()
```

and

```
$eloquentEntity->relation()->count()
```

sometimes return two different values (the first one is sometimes zero). The weird thing is that only sometimes the values are different even though all $eloquentEntity are retrieved in bulk.

`$eloquentEntity` is fetched from the database using

```
$eloquentEntities = EloquentEntity::with(['relation'])->get()
```

so everything contained in that relation should be available when `count()` is run on the relation collection.

Does somebody have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try `sizeof($eloquentEntity->relation)`

Comment: check this https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-count

Comment: use this `count($eloquentEntity->relation);`

Comment: Have you already retrieved the relation before using `$eloquentEntity->relation->count()`? If so, has it been constrained in any way e.g. where clauses?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution: We're using UUIDs as primary keys and we forgot to set `public $keyType = 'string';` on our Models. They were interpreting the keys as integers by default which for some reason works most of the time with UUIDs.

Answer (score 2):

You can count relation amount using `withCount()` method. Something like this

```php
$eloquentEntities = EloquentEntity::withCount('relation')->get();
```

```php
foreach ($eloquentEntities as $row) {
    echo $row->relation_count; // to print relation count
}
```

You can also see [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) for more information

Answer (score 0):

You  can use count attribute  eg:

```
  public function getReferalUsersAttribute()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\User', 'referal_id' , 'id')->count();

    }
```

and Append attribute like that in your Model

```
protected $appends = [
        'referal_users'
    ];
```

Answer (score 0):

if count relation entities try like this code

```
$posts = App\Post::withCount('comments')->get();
foreach ($posts as $post) {
 echo $post->comments_count;
}
```

[document](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)